# Check if user is authenticated synchronously

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a user is authenticated in my app. The issue is I don't want to be cursed by the JS Lord if I use it in synchronous manner.
What I want ideally is to have a function

```
Api.User.isAuthenticated()
```

which I would run like this:

```
if (Api.User.isAuthenticated())
    {
        Views.renderDashboard()
    }
else
    {
        Views.renderLogin()
    }
```

Right now I implemented this function as a promise and it works fine but looks overcomplicated for simple things like checking user login status.

I use [qwest](https://github.com/pyrsmk/qwest) library to make XHR requests. It returns promises, code looks like this:

```
Api.User.isAuthenticated = function(token)
    {
        return qwest.get('/session', token)
    }

Api.User.isAuthenticated(token)
    .then(function (response) {
        //
    })
    .catch(function (e, response) {
        //
    });
```

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Can you show the actual code? The current code looks like synchronous only.

Comment: Can you post the current 'overcomplicated' code?

Comment: Also, what work does Api.User.isAuthenticated do?  Does it call asynchronous (I/O) methods?

Answer (score 1):

If your authentication method requires async, you could try simply using a callback:

```
Api.User.checkAuthentication = function(token, callback) {
  qwest.get('/session', token).then(function (response) {
    // Check your response here, send true or false to the callback as appropriate
    callback(true);
  })
  .catch(function (e, response) {
    // You should probably notify the user of the error here, that it wasn't
    // just an invalid username/password combo
    callback(false);
  });
}

Api.User.checkAuthentication('token', function (authenticated) {
  if (authenticated) {
    Views.renderDashboard();
  } else {
    Views.renderLogin();
  }
})
```

This whole method could be put into a function, say, `checkAuth()`, which can be called when needed. You could go further and pass callbacks to checkAuth, to run custom code when we check if the user is authenticated or not.

Comment: Passing callbacks leads more nested and hard to read code than Promises.  That's what promises addressed.

Comment: ^ I was about to add a comment to this effect. Promises can reduce indentation waterfalls, and lead to generally easier to follow code.
The OP has however stated for this particular case, he finds promises too much, and for this instance where we know there will probably be only 1 nested callback, I would agree. I think a callback for this scenario makes good sense.